# My Mail app (MacOS Catalina 10.15.3) displays phantom unread messages

Tags: macos, mail.app, catalina

My MacBook displays 1 unread message in smart mailbox while there are none. 
It used to work OK, but recently it shows unread messages. When I click on this Smart Mailbox it doesn't display any messages. Settings for the Smart Mailbox is OK. I tried methods described in different topics but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I saw this recently too. I just hope it's not gmail doing this. rebuilding the mailboxes worked for me, temporarily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Quit **Mail** if it’s open.
2. In `~/Library/Mail/V7/MailData`, delete any file that begins with “**Envelope Index**,” such as Envelope Index or Envelope Index-shm.
3. Your home **Library** folder is hidden by default. To display it, choose **Finder** > “**Go to Folder**” and then enter “`~/Library.`”
4. Open **Mail**.
5. Mail creates new Envelope Index files. This process may take a few minutes, depending on how many messages Mail is reindexing.

It will fix your issue.

Comment: This solution fixed the unread count problem for me too, but it also shuffled messages around. Old messages that were in my archive (or in various local folders) reappeared in my inbox. Nothing important (no lost message), but it was annoying to have to clean up the mess.

Comment: You shouldn't try this answer without a backup. After deleting and re-creating the index files, my inbox is populated with mails moved _years_ ago, some mails are sorted into newly created temporary folders. The phantom unread messages are there, as before.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix that by simply turning off and back on the Mail service sync in the Accounts settings:

1. Open the Mail app and go to Accounts settings.
   [image: OSX Mail menu]
2. Uncheck the Mail option for the account that shows the wrong unread count.
   [image: OSX Mail Accounts settings]
3. Check it back on and close the Accounts settings.
4. At this point your smart mailboxes might be empty but don't worry - restarting the app should fix that.

Comment: It messes with the smart inboxes that doesn't dispaly anymore the messages from the account having been turned off and on again

Comment: Update : the missing mails are coming back after a "rebuild" on the root inbox of the account, see https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/guide/mail/mlhlp1227/mac

Comment: Thank you, it worked well. The other solution did not work this time.

Answer (score 0):

I added more rules to the Smart Mailbox (mainly read after and read before) until there were only very few mails. Then I tried unread/read on them and finally pinpoint the exact mail that causes this hassle. Since it's not a really important mail, I simply deleted it and the unread number disappeared.